# Script Conversion 2.7 to 3 (sockets)

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, exception, rdp, recv

I'm trying to convert a script written in python2.7 to python3.
The first hurdle is how byte strings are handled between the two, which I believe I've worked around.

The script I'm looking at is this one: https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/tools/r...r-checker/

The first hurdle was how byte strings are handled between the two, which I believe I've worked around.

## python3

```
s.send(packet.encode('utf-8'))
```

## python2.7

```
s.send(packet)
```

The next issue seems to be around the implementation of sockets.

```
for n in list(enc_protocols.keys()):
    packet = X224_CONNECTION_REQUEST % n

    print(binascii.hexlify(n.encode('utf-8')))

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, port))
    #s.sendall(packet.encode('utf-8'))
    s.send(packet.encode('utf-8'))
    #s.send(packet)
    response = s.recv(1024)
    #response = s.recv(4096)

    if (response[3] == "\x0b"):
        enc_protocols["\x00"][1] = True
        break
    else:
        if (response[11] == "\x02"):
            enc_protocols[n][1] = True
        else:
            errors[response[15]] = True

    #print binascii.hexlify(response)

    s.close()
```

Specifically this line:

```
response = s.recv(1024)
```

It throws the error:

> "Traceback (most recent call last): File "rdp_check_ciphers.py", line
>   81, in  response = s.recv(1024) ConnectionResetError: [Errno
>   104] Connection reset by peer"

I'm just after some pointers as to what is likely the problem if anyone has experienced this sort of issue themselves.

I might add, the code works with python2.7 against my Windows 7 VM. I just don't understand why moving the python3 gives me a ConnectionResetError.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem was to do with byte strings being handled differently between the versions of python.

For example, the following changes needed to be made:

```
enc_protocols = {b'\x00' : ["Native RDP", False], b'\x01' : ["SSL", False], b'\x03' : ["CredSSP", False]}
enc_methods = {b'\x01' : ["40-bit RC4", False], b'\x02' : ["128-bit RC4", False], b'\x08' : ["56-bit RC4", False], b'\x10' : ["FIPS 140-1", False]}
enc_levels = {b'\x00' : ["None", False], b'\x01' : ["Low", False], b'\x02' : ["Client Compatible", False], b'\x03' : ["High", False], b'\x04' : ["FIPS 140-1", False]}
```